# How to get current page number in sap ui5 Table Pagination?

Tags: sapui5

Can anyone help me to get current page number in sap ui5 Table Pagination .

For example if am in second page in pagination I have to get count of 2 if it is third page i have to get count of 3.

Answer (score -1):

Hi krishnakumar sasthaiyan,

First get the ID of the table, and below line of code should work.

sap.ui.getCore().byId("TABLE_ID")._oPaginator.getCurrentPage();